# angular2 themes based on routes

Tags: angular

I have two routes /books and /paintings

I want to include the link tag based on route in index.html

For /books route, i want to include

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/reading-theme.css" />
```

For /paintings route, i want to include

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/gallery-theme.css" />
```

Both the theme files have css that style html background differently

reading-theme.css

```
html, body {
    background-color: #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

gallery-theme.css

```
html, body {
    background-color: #edb2b2;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

if i include these files in the respective component's styleUrls like this

```
styleUrls: ['../../assets/css/reading-theme.css', './books.component.css']
```

the css was not getting applied to html.

How can i use different theme files based on routes? Is there any service like Title service that i can use to set the link hrefs dynamically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this `@import '../../assets/css/reading-theme.css';`  in your component's CSS file

Comment: @Vikas I think the import starts from `src`, meaning it should be `@import 'src/assets/css/reading-theme.css'`. But still, I don't think it would work.

Comment: angular is smart. using import, i only got component styles, not html styles

Answer (score 0):

If you base your style on routes, then you should just set the styles on your components.

I see you tried and failed, because that's not how to do it. As far as I know, there's only one `html` and one `body` tags, and they're not in your component, but in the `index.html` file.

This is what your style should look like :

```
* {
  background-color: #edb2b2;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Because Angular encapsulates the view, this style will only be applied to the route you're on (unless you change the encapsulation).